# Byte to int, float, NSString conversion

Tags: objective-c

Are there any methods in objective C for converting byte to int, float and NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first are C-types. No conversion is needed, just assign them:

```
byte b = ...;

int x = b;
float f = b;
```

Converting to NSString could be done using `stringWithFormat:`, a `NSNumberFormatter` and many more methods. This is the easiest:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", b];
```

If you want it printed in hex, use `@"%x"` (for lowercase letters) or `@"%X"` (for capital letters) instead.

Comment: What if I have an array of four byte and I want to convert it into int.

Comment: bitshift and add them. Like so: `int x = (arr[0] << 12) + (arr[1] << 8) + (arr[2] << 4) + arr[3]`

Answer (score 0):

You could get an [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) from [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with `initWithData:encoding:` and then transform it into int or float by calling `intValue` and `floatValue`